# Confused about / with?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I've encountered this question today, what I actually said was

> I'm confused with these two questions.

Then I thought, "Should I say confused with?"

Dictionary says **about** should follow confused.

Can anyone tell me whether both of them are right?

Answer (score 14):

"Confused with" is generally used when you fail to distinguish/mistake one for another. For example, "I always confuse Tanya with her sister".

On the other hand, "confused about" is used when "confuse" is given its literal meaning. For example, "I am confused about what to do with this degree that I've got".

Depending on the context, either could be correct, as they give a different meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Sam Karem's examples are practical and concise:

> "I always confuse Tanya with her sister."
>
> "I am confused about what to do with this degree that I've got".

But in addition to that, it would be better if we note that:

- The word "confused" is an adjective, as in "be *confused about*".
- The word "confuse" is a verb, as in "people *confuse* A *with* B".

references:

- http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=confuse
- http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=confused

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, preposition choice is a matter of opinion and personal preference.

*With* is perfectly acceptable in this case. In fact, according to Dictionary.com, one of the [official definitions of *with*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/with?o=O) is

> In regard(s) to

You could easily rewrite your example as

> I am confused *in regards to* these two questions.

However, *about* is also acceptable, as it can potentially have [exactly the same definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/about?s=t) as *with*.

In conclusion, in this case, it's simply a matter of preference. Either is correct.

Which one sounds better to you?